# Get 2D location from 3D point

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a THREE.Vector3 with location x, y, z of a mesh in the viewer. How can I get a corresponding 2D point on canvas? I would like to place something x, y at the same location where the 3D model is located in the viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [worldToClient(point)](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/) method (part of Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D), the *point* parameters is a THREE.Vector3 point in world space coordinates. Below is a piece of the documentation.

> Calculates the pixel position in client space coordinates of a point
>   in world space. See also clientToWorld().